# what is "set.eq.s32.b32" assembly?

Tags: assembly, cuda, instructions

I am trying to read a piece of CUDA code from [this github repo](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nv-wavenet) and came across this:

```
__device__ __forceinline__ bool isNegativeZero(float a) {
    int ret;
    asm volatile("{  set.eq.s32.b32 %0, %1, %2;}\n" : "=r"(ret) : "f"(a), "r"(0x80000000));
    return ret;
}
```

I am not sure what the assembly instructions are, but form the context of the entire file, the function seems to do more than merely checking if the float is negative zero.

I would really appreciate a high-level explanation of the function.

Comment: From where on GitHub?  That would make it easier to find out what architecture this is for, and go look up the instruction in a manual for that architecture for you.  But on a high level it looks like it sets an integer register to non-zero if the input float is bitwise equal to IEEE FP `-0.0` (sign bit set, all other bits clear).  Then `return ret` booleanizes that `int` to 0 or 1 instead of 0 / non-zero.

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks peter! This is from https://github.com/NVIDIA/nv-wavenet and this piece of code is within nv_wavener_persistent.cu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am not sure what the assembly instructions are...

The instructions come from [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html#comparison-and-selection-instructions-set).

```
set.eq.s32.b32 dest, valx, valy
```

means "set the value of dest if valx is equal to valy". Here `valx` is the input value to the function and `valy` is `0x80000000`, and `dest` is the return value of the function `ret`. The rest of the function is just standard gcc derived inline assembly syntax, also documented [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/inline-ptx-assembly/index.html).

You can check for yourself [here](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) that `-0.0f` is `10000000000000000000000000000000` or `0x80000000` in IEEE 754 binary32 representation.

Therefore the function returns true if `a` is negative 0, checking for bitwise equality.

> ... but form [sic] the context of the entire file..the function seems to do more than merely checking if the float is negative zero.

Hopefully it is now apparent that this is not the case.